# WCF, how stop stop log4net file being created on build

Tags: wcf, service, log4net

I am having a problem with the log4net file in a WCF service i have created.

When i build and run my WCF services it created log4net then errors with the following...

"Could not load file or assembly 'log4net' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

When I delete the fle from the bin folder and refresh the browser the services run fine.

So, how can i stop the log4net being created in the bin foler when i build my project? as i dont need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your service project, you probably have a reference to a log4net assemly. Or the log4net assembly is referenced in another assemly that is referenced in your service project. Somehow it is chained-in as a dependency for your service to be deployed and is therefore copied into your bin folder.

Find the reference to the log4net assembly, select it and select **Properties** from its context menu. In the Properties window set **Copy Local** to false. This will prevent the assembly to be copied into the output bin folder.